# flyway sql file is not able to open another file

Tags: java, postgresql, file, flyway

In my Java project, I am using flyway migration (which is working). In one of my migration file, I have to read a svg file from resource folder to save in a table (column). I am using postgres Database. For that operation, I am using [pg_read_file()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-GENFILE-TABLE)  method.

If I provide absolute path to file, it's working. But with relative path, it's not working out.

```
src
├── main
│   ├── java
│   └── resources
│       ├── local-images
│       │   └──image.svg
│       └── db
│       │   └──migration
│       │      └──V1__populate_table.sql
        └── application.properties
```

**application.properties**

```
# https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-execute-flyway-database-migrations-on-startup
# provides location of the database migrations sql files 
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration
```

**V1__populate_table.sql**

```
INSERT INTO public.image(
        image_id, file)
        VALUES ('656cc4e8-9e50-1111-1111-303cdc05a058', pg_read_file('resources/local-images/image.svg')::bytea);
```

**Error**

```
SQL State  : 58P01
Error Code : 0
Message    : ERROR: could not open file "resources/local-images/image.svg" for reading: No such file or directory
```

I tried putting both `.sql` and `image.svg` file in same folder, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading your resources file using the java `classloader`:

```java
InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("local-images/image.svg");
byte[] fileBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
```

```
INSERT INTO public.image (image_id, file)
VALUES ('656cc4e8-9e50-1111-1111-303cdc05a058', bytes::bytea);
```

#### EDIT

`pg_read_file()` reads files from the file system **relative to the data directory** of the cluster, **not the application classpath**. To read the file from the resources directory you can:

1. Provide the absolute path of the file
2. Provide a path relative to the data directory

You could try copying that file from resources to a location on the file system and then use `pg_read_file()` to read the file from that location before executing the SQL statement.

Comment: But, how I can pass that to SQL file? Because this file is loaded from flyway during server start-up.

Comment: Which one is "the data directory"?