# Relative Path within flyway migration SQL scripts

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

I want to load data to a column via flyway migration

```sql
update PUBLIC.user set image=FILE_READ('./../../assets/images/testuser.png') where username='testuser';
```

but I get a `FileNotFoundException`. If I use the full path it is working but I want to use a relative path here as it can vary on each system. The path used is relative to the migration file that is executed.

This is the directory scructure within the resource folder:

```
├───db
    ├───assets
    │   └───images
    ├───fixtures
    ├───migration
    └───special
        ├───h2
        └───postgresql
```

The migration script is located within `db/special/h2` and the images are within `db/assets/images`.

Flyway paths:

```
  flyway:
    locations: "db/migration,/db/special/{vendor}"
```

How can this be resolved properly?

Comment: I would guess that the placement of your migration files is not relevant :)
If the flyway migration scripts see other files at all, I guess the path would be with root in your `/resources` folder. I have not tried myself, this is just a wild guess.

Comment: I tried several variants based on resource directory but without success so far.

Comment: Have you tried `FILE_READ('./db/assets/images/testuser.png')`, `FILE_READ('/db/assets/images/testuser.png')` and `FILE_READ('db/assets/images/testuser.png')`? I really **doubt** that the flyway migration scripts run in the context of their source directory.

Comment: Yes all of the combination mentioned. I do not really know which base path flyway uses for such files even if i copy the file directly to the h2 folder I get the same error message. So I guess you cannot use relative paths. I will try flyway placeholder to get the base directory to the resource folder with maven resource filtering although that seems a bit of an overhead for just a simple migration task...

Comment: I found an identical question with a non-accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75362075/2886891 Try if it helps you.

Comment: At the first glance it looks to me like you will have to run `maven-resources-plugin` (https://www.baeldung.com/maven-copy-files) to copy your `images` files to the folder from where the SQL script is actually run.

Comment: Thanks I already thought using the a java based migration as I have access to the files there via classloader.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the following `BaseJavaMigration` class.

```
package db.migration;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.flywaydb.core.api.migration.BaseJavaMigration;
import org.flywaydb.core.api.migration.Context;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.AbstractLobCreatingPreparedStatementCallback;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SingleConnectionDataSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.DefaultLobHandler;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.LobCreator;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.LobHandler;

public class V1_2_3__ImageLoader extends BaseJavaMigration {

    private static final Map<String, String> IMAGE_MAP = new HashMap<>();

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(V1_2_3__ImageLoader.class);

    /**
     * Default constructor.
     */
    public V1_2_3__ImageLoader() {
        IMAGE_MAP.put("testadmin", "testadmin.png");
        IMAGE_MAP.put("testmanager", "testmanager.png");
        IMAGE_MAP.put("testuser", "testuser.png");
    }

    @Override
    public void migrate(Context context) throws Exception {
        final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate =
                new JdbcTemplate(new SingleConnectionDataSource(context.getConnection(), true));
        int counter = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : IMAGE_MAP.entrySet()) {
            ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
            InputStream inputStream = cl.getResourceAsStream("db/assets/images/" + entry.getValue());

            if (inputStream == null) {
                LOGGER.info("Could not find file {}.", entry.getValue());
                continue;
            }
            byte[] imageData = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

            // insert binary data to database
            String sqlQuery = "update PUBLIC.sd_user set image=? where username=?";
            LobHandler lobHandler = new DefaultLobHandler();
            Integer result =
                    jdbcTemplate.execute(sqlQuery, new AbstractLobCreatingPreparedStatementCallback(lobHandler) {
                        protected void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, LobCreator lobCreator) throws SQLException {
                            ps.setString(2, entry.getKey());
                            lobCreator.setBlobAsBytes(ps, 1, imageData);
                        }
                    });

            if (result != null) {
                counter = counter + result;
            }
        }
        LOGGER.info("Updated {} user images.", counter);
    }
}
```